# Euler equation guess and verify

Tags: macroeconomics

So I have the Euler condition written as follows: $$\frac{1}{k_t^a-k_{t+1}}=\frac{a\beta k_{t+1}^{a-1}}{k_{t+1}^a-k_{t+2}}$$
and it says that $k_{t+1}$ takes the form $gk_t^a$, where g is an unknown to be determined. I know the result is $k_{t+1}=a\beta k_t^a$, but don't know how the derivation goes to reach this result.

From the hint, I got that $^_{+1}−_{+2}=^{−1}_{+1}^_−^_{+1}$, we divide by ^_{+1} and what I get is $1−=−$. Now based on the results, $g$ should somehow be $$, but I'm stuck here

Comment: Are you sure it's not that $k_{t+1}=gk_t^a$?

Comment: @HerrK. yes, my mistake

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Hint:

Note that
\begin{equation}
k_{t+1}=gk_t^a \quad\Rightarrow\quad g=\frac{k_{t+1}}{k_t^a}=\frac{k_{t+2}}{k_{t+1}^a}.
\end{equation}

Rearrange your Euler condition into a form such that you can use $g$ to sub-out the above ratios. Then it should be straightforward to solve for $g$.

Comment: I edited it but I'm not sure if what I wrote is correct :/

Comment: @MaybelineLee: Try cross-multiplying the denominators in the original equation, and then divide both sides by $k_{t+1}^a$. Simplify using the hint to get an equation that only involves $g,a,\beta$. Lastly solve for $g$.

Comment: So I'm going through the derivations again on this one and it's still confusing me. We have $k_{t+1}^a-k_{t+2}=abk_{t+1}^{a-1}k_t^a-abk_{t+1}^a$, we divide by $k_{t+1}^a$ and what I get is $1-g=\frac{ab}{g}-ab$. Now based on the results, g should somehow be $ab$ but I'm just not getting it.

Comment: @MaybelineLee: Solving $1-g=\frac{ab}{g}-ab$ for $g$ yields $g=ab$ or $g=1$.